# Spree static page routing issue adding about page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I am trying to add a aboutUs page into a spree app using Spree Static Content. I have the following error when I click on the link of the About Us page[image]

I have the following layout

> layouts/aboutUs.html.erb

In the routes.rb file I have the following code.

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # This line mounts Spree's routes at the root of your application.
  # This means, any requests to URLs such as /products, will go to Spree::ProductsController.
  # If you would like to change where this engine is mounted, simply change the :at option to something different.
  #
  # We ask that you don't use the :as option here, as Spree relies on it being the default of "spree"
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, at: '/'
          # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

          get 'Yellow',   to: 'static_pages#aboutUs'
end
```

Comment: It appears like it's looking for a partial (with an undercore) and not in the layouts directory.  Look at that error more closely, you can see what directories it's looking for the file.  btw - I recommend all lower case file names - no camel case, use underscores between words - `_about_us.html.erb`

Comment: @Swards so to what folder should I add the _about_us.html.erb file?

Comment: I think `/views/spree/static_content` is the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

I know is late and you might have solved your problem a long time ago but for those who get here looking for an answer.

The issue was using the `/layout` and not `/static_content`.

If you are using a controller and inside the method aren't rendering with an specific route then you should use the predefined route to get to place the render file.

Quick answer:
 place the `aboutUs.html.erb` file at `/static_content` not at `/layout` having the following file location:

> {app_route}/static_content/aboutUs.html.erb